# Интервал между датами

Tags: javascript

Имеется написанный мной такой код

```js
function getDateTime(dt){
  let now = new Date(dt);
  let d = ('0'+now.getDate()).slice(-2);
  let m = ('0'+(now.getMonth()+1)).slice(-2);
  let y = now.getFullYear();
  let h = ('0'+now.getHours()).slice(-2);
  let i = ('0'+now.getMinutes()).slice(-2);
  let s = ('0'+now.getSeconds()).slice(-2);
  let ms = ('00'+now.getMilliseconds()).slice(-3);
  return h+':'+i+':'+s+' '+d+'.'+m+'.'+y;
}
function intervalDate(dt){
  let res = {};
  res.seconds = parseInt((dt/1000)%60);
  res.minutes = parseInt((dt/(1000*60))%60);
  res.hours = parseInt((dt/(1000*60*60))%24);
  res.days = parseInt(dt/(1000*60*60*24));
  return res;
}

let dt1 = 1575932802452;
let dt2 = 1575932934285; // Date.now()

let dt3 = dt2 - dt1;

console.log(getDateTime(dt1));
console.log(getDateTime(dt2));

console.log(intervalDate(dt3));
```

Почему то иногда не правильно считает интервал даты.

И данного примера выводит:

```
"seconds": 11
```

а должен:

```
"seconds": 12
```

Дорогие друзья, объясните пожалуйста что не так в коде?

Ведь по логике должен же правильно все показывать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
function getDateTime(dt){
  let now = new Date(dt);
  let d = ('0'+now.getDate()).slice(-2);
  let m = ('0'+(now.getMonth()+1)).slice(-2);
  let y = now.getFullYear();
  let h = ('0'+now.getHours()).slice(-2);
  let i = ('0'+now.getMinutes()).slice(-2);
  let s = ('0'+now.getSeconds()).slice(-2);
  let ms = ('00'+now.getMilliseconds()).slice(-3);
  return h+':'+i+':'+s+' '+d+'.'+m+'.'+y;
}
function intervalDate(dt){
  let res = {};
  console.log((dt/1000)%60);
  res.seconds = Math.round((dt/1000)%60);
  res.minutes = parseInt((dt/(1000*60))%60);
  res.hours = parseInt((dt/(1000*60*60))%24);
  res.days = parseInt(dt/(1000*60*60*24));
  return res;
}

let dt1 = 1575932802452;
let dt2 = 1575932934285; // Date.now()

let dt3 = dt2 - dt1;

console.log(getDateTime(dt1));
console.log(getDateTime(dt2));

console.log(intervalDate(dt3));
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, теперь я понял, дело было в миллисекундах. `parseInt` оказывается просто обрезал до точки.

Comment: @bolatol377 Пожалуйста. Успехов.